# Updating Related Record Fires email alert assigned to Parent Record

Tags: process-builder, email-alert

I have created process builder process which sends email alert as an immediate action.

Opportunity Stage = Closed Won -> immediate action send email to entire sales team.

A related record to this opportunity record is commission record which finance manager updates about 30 days later once final payment is received from customer.

Once commission record is updated, Emails are once again sent which is similar to

Opportunity Stage = Closed Won -> immediate action send email to entire sales team.

How can i stop this from happening?

Thanks
Prashant

**Update: 
commission record updates a field on opportunity record called Commission Request (Picklist, default NO), 
When all fields of commission record are filled and saved process builder updates Commission Request field to Yes. A validation rule is commission request field should be YES, only then the record can be saved to Closed Won.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your child record (Commission) has some kind of functionality attached that makes a record update to the parent Opportunity. This might be either automation that performs a field update on Opportunity, or one or more Roll-Up Summary Fields from Commission to Opportunity, or a trigger.

Additionally, your Closed Won process is configured to fire on any change to Opportunity, rather than firing on "specified changes". For this reason, it goes off any time the Opportunity is updated while in Closed Won stage. You should be able to validate this theory by placing an Opportunity in Closed Won stage and subsequently editing a field. You should see the email go out at that point.

You can fix this by changing the process to fire only on "specified changes", meaning only when the Opportunity enters Closed Won stage.

(This is one likely theory based on your description, but there are a wide variety of reasons this could happen based on how your org is actually customized, and you would need to pin down the cause more accurately to get a definitive answer).

Comment: Hi David, you are right! I have updated the question with new information.

Comment: In the process builder, i did not find any option on specified changes, any guidance on how to fire email alert only on closed-won but only once? Thanks Prashant

Comment: It's under the Advanced disclosure triangle at the bottom of the screen where you edit a criteria node in Process Builder. Just check the box "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?"